# Need to fetch only "carname" from Firebase Realtime Database but getting a whole list

Tags: json, swift, firebase, api, firebase-realtime-database

Just stuck on this for the whole day and thought I'd ask for help.
So this is my realtime database and I just need to extract the "carname" so I can set my label of my cell to whatever value is stored for the name of the car in the Firebase Realtime Database.

This is my first time using Firebase. I'm learning. Thanks.

This is my realtime database in Firebase
[image: My Realtime Database in Firebase]

What I have tried
(self.myyTitle is actually a declared variable above as String?)

```
        ref?.child("users").child("photodetails").child(String(indexPath.item)).child("carname").getData { [self] (error,snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting data \(error)")
        }
        else if snapshot.exists() {
            print("Got Data \(snapshot.value!)")
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{
                let post = dict["carname"] as! String
                print(post)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.myTitle.text = self.myyTitle
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("No data available")
        }
        
    }
    return cell
}
```

[image: What I have tried]

The console (Gives whole list output)

[image: Console Output]

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Updated it for you.  @FrankvanPuffelen

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation: [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data)

If you want get list of data in side photodetails that refs try to follow this code :

```
self.ref.child("photodetails").observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let photoDe = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let carname = photoDe["carname"] as! String
        
        print(carname)
        }
    }
```

Please remove this : `String(indexPath.item)` don't indexpath

```
    ref?.child("users").child("photodetails").child(String(indexPath.item)).child("carname").getData { [self] (error,snapshot) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error getting data \(error)")
        }
        else if snapshot.exists() {
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:Any]{
                let post = dict["carname"] as! String
                print(post)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    cell.myTitle.text = self.myyTitle
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            print("No data available")
        }
        
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Hi Sonu, I'm using the indexPath.item because as you can see in my realtime database, there are children 0,1,2,3. And at each index there are different details of a car as you can see.

I want to display each car details such as "carname" in a Collection View.
So each cell has a unique carname fetched from realtime database. 
Do you understand what I tried to do?

Comment: you can do looping statement in side firebase callback function for loop already exist 
for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let photoDe = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let carname = photoDe["carname"] as! String

Comment: how do I add indexpath.item in that for loop? I don't get your point?